# WordPress Restore

Tags: wordpress, restore

in my previous laptop I created some demo websites using WordPress (xamp) and database as localhost/phpmyadmin
I changed my laptop recently and only copied the htdocs folder from the xampp folder
and didnt do anything with the data base
how can  I get my sited back
i only have the htdocs folder which I had in my previous laptop

I dont have acess to that old laptop anymore
I did not exported any database from that laptop
in my new laptop I only have the htdocs folder from the previous laptop
I tried creating the database of the same name I had in the old laptop but It gave me a fresh wordpress not the site I have

I tried creating the database of the same name I had in the old laptop but It gave me a fresh wordpress not the site I have

Comment: The WP database contains all the dynamic site contents, i.e. everything that's written in the main part of pages and posts, so if you don't have a backup of the database, your site contents are lost – sorry.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.